# Plot the lines (nodes) for the given value from NDsolve output

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, programming, finite-element-method

I want to plot lines for a specific single value from the output in Nsolve (we need to find these nodes from the output **ufun**, then plot them).

```
 ufun = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 10, u[x, 0] == 0, 
    u[x, 1] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotRange -> MinMax[ufun["ValuesOnGrid"]], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

The results something like, the given value is **1.5**, the lines are denoted by **red**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what is meant by "nodes" but this gives the indicated graphics:

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 10, u[x, 0] == 0, 
    u[x, 1] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
cp = ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   PlotRange -> MinMax[ufun["ValuesOnGrid"]], 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic], AspectRatio -> Automatic];
lines = ContourPlot[ufun[x, y] == 1.5, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Red];
Show[cp, lines]
```

[image]

This gives the points computed by `ContourPlot` for each line:

```
Cases[Normal@lines, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity]
(* two lines/tables of points/nodes
{
 {{0.`, 0.35518590998042887`}, {0.0020263424518760335`, 
   0.35511651469098104`}, ..., {1.`, 0.35518590998043176`}},
 {{0.`, 0.8443496801705759`}, {0.012332990750256536`, 
   0.8448098663926003`}, ..., {1.`, 0.8443496801705764`}}
 }
*)
```

Comment: thanks, it is solved now!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM You're welcome.

Comment: can we get these selected points (nodes) as a table/list in MMA ?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM You want the coordinates of the points on each red line? That can be done. Note they are not points computed by `NDSolve`.  They are computed by `ContourPlot` from the interpolation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) as follows:

```
ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotRange -> MinMax[ufun["ValuesOnGrid"]], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic],
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{1.5}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, CapForm["Butt"], Red],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand that right that you want to include the red lines in the plot?
In that case have a look at the code below:

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 10, u[x, 0] == 0, 
u[x, 1] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
PlotRange -> MinMax[ufun["ValuesOnGrid"]], 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{0, 0.85}, {1, 0.85}}], 
Line[{{0, 0.35}, {1, 0.35}}]}]
```